# R: GGPLOT2 GEOM_COL()

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, shiny

mi duda es como cambiar el nombre de las variables que se muestran sobre el eje X. Es decir en vez de mostrarme "20180701" quiero que muestre "Junio 2018" y así con los demás casos también. Adjunto una imagen para que puedan entender mejor.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Juan! Puse una respuesta "genérica" sobre formateado de fechas en R. No estoy seguro de que te sirva, porque dependería de como estés haciendo el gráfico. Si compartes el código y un ejemplo mínimo de los datos con los que estás haciendo el gráfico sería mucho más fácil encontrar una respuesta correcta. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No queda del todo claro el contexto en el que estás haciendo el gráfico, al parecer es dentro de `shiny`. No sé si ahí hay otra manera de hacerlo, pero dentro de R "normal" se podría reformatear la fecha.

El primer paso es asegurarte que la variable que aparece en el gráfico como `Período` esté correctamente formateada como fecha. `class(Período)` debería regresarte `Date`.

Después cambias el formato en el que se ve la fecha a uno en el que muestra el Mes (con caracteres) y en día en número.

Va un ejemplo completo:

```
Período <- "20180701"

Período <- as.Date(Período ,"%Y%m%d")
[1] "2018-07-01"

class(Período)
[1] Date

format.Date(Período, "%B %Y")
[1] "July 2018"
```

Las dos funciones están vectorizadas, así que debería transformar a un vector completo. En mi caso obtengo `"July 2018" por mi configuración de`locale`.

> `format.Date()` NO regresa una fecha, sino una cadena de caracteres. Eso podría complicarte el orden de las barras en el gráfico, ya que `Abril 2018` estaría antes de `Enero 2018`. Dependerá de cómo estés haciendo tu gráfico. Hay formas de solucionarlo, si estás trabajando con `ggplot2` sería pasando esta transformación a `scale_x_date()`. No sé en shiny.